# Add-Type variations: -MemberType vs. -TypeDefinition parameters

Tags: .net, powershell, types, add-type

Can someone explain the difference between this approach to Add-Type

```
$definition = [Text.StringBuilder]"" 
    [void]$definition.AppendLine('[DllImport("user32.dll")]') 
    [void]$definition.AppendLine('public static extern int LoadString(IntPtr h, uint id, System.Text.StringBuilder sb, int maxBuffer);') 
    [void]$definition.AppendLine('[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]') 
    [void]$definition.AppendLine('public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string s);') 
    Add-Type -memberDefinition:$definition.ToString() -name:Utility -namespace:PxTools
```

And something like this

```
Add-Type -typeDefinition @"
public class BasicTest
{
  public static int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a + b);
    }
  public int Multiply(int a, int b)
    {
    return (a * b);
    }
}
"@
```

I see examples of the latter quite often, but the former I have only ever seen in some sample code to Pin to Taskbar. Are these just two different ways to skin a cat, or is the former required in some use cases?
And, if both are valid all the time, what would it look like to use the latter method with the code in the former?

EDIT: I considered making this a new thread, but it seems to me this is an expansion on the original question, so hopefully this is the correct approach.

I have implemented code based on what I learned from [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/b66434f1-4b3f-4a94-8dc3-e406eb30b750) post...

```
$targetFile = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Snipping Tool.lnk"
$action = 'PinToTaskbar'

$verbs = @{  
    'PinToStartMenu' = 5381 
    'UnpinFromStartMenu' = 5382 
    'PinToTaskbar' = 5386 
    'UnpinFromTaskbar' = 5387
}

try { 
    $type = [type]"PxTools.Utility" 
}  catch { 
    $definition = [Text.StringBuilder]"" 
    [void]$definition.AppendLine('[DllImport("user32.dll")]') 
    [void]$definition.AppendLine('public static extern int LoadString(IntPtr h, uint id, System.Text.StringBuilder sb, int maxBuffer);') 
    [void]$definition.AppendLine('[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]') 
    [void]$definition.AppendLine('public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string s);') 
    Add-Type -memberDefinition:$definition.ToString() -name:Utility -namespace:PxTools          
} 
if ($script:Shell32 -eq $null) {         
    $script:Shell32 = [PxTools.Utility]::LoadLibrary("shell32.dll") 
} 
$maxVerbLength = 255 
$verb = new-object Text.StringBuilder "", $maxVerbLength 
[void][PxTools.Utility]::LoadString($script:Shell32, $verbs.$action, $verb, $maxVerbLength) 
$verbAsString = $verb.ToString()
try {
    $path = Split-Path $targetFile -parent -errorAction:stop
    $file = Split-Path $targetFile -leaf -errorAction:stop
    $shell = New-Object -com:"Shell.Application" -errorAction:stop 
    $folder = $shell.Namespace($path)    
    $target = $($folder.Parsename($file)).Verbs() | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $verbAsString}
    $target.DoIt()
    Write-Host "$($action): $file"
} catch {
    Write-Host "Error managing shortcut"
}
```

Now I have three questions about refactoring this.

1: How would I refactor the Add-Type to use a Here-String?
EDIT: This seems to work, so I'll revise the question to be, is this the best/most elegant solution, or could it be improved?

```
Add-Type -memberDefinition:@"
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int LoadString(IntPtr h, uint id, System.Text.StringBuilder sb, int maxBuffer);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string s);
"@  -name:Utility -namespace:PxTools
```

2: Test.StringBuilder is used both as the type of the $definition string and in the LoadString method. Is this required, or could this be implemented without using StringBuilder at all?
EDIT: I eliminated SB as the data type in the refactor above, but not sure about doing it in LoadString. Probably because I am still trying to get my head around exactly what the code is doing, before I go changing it.

3: Does the `$script:Shell32` bit need to be handled like this, or could it not be rolled into the Type instead? And, is the original Global scope (which I changed to Script scope) really necessary? Seems to me that unless I was doing this hundreds of times calling LoadLibrary multiple times wouldn't be that big a deal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Re 1:

Yes, using a here-string this way is the best approach.

<sup>On a side note, using `:` to separate parameter names from their values works, but is unusual; typically, a *space* is used (e.g., `-name Utility` rather than `-name:Utility`).</sup>

- Re 2:

There is NO good reason to use `[System.Text.StringBuilder]` here in the type definition.
Use a here-string, regular string, or a string array.
Aside from use in a Windows API call, as you demonstrate, the only reason you'd ever consider using `[System.Text.StringBuilder]` in PowerShell is if performance is paramount and you need to build up a very large string from dynamically created pieces.

<sup>Gordon himself notes that using `[System.Text.StringBuilder]` in the `sb` parameter of the `LoadString()` Windows API function is necessary, because it is an *out* parameter that *receives* a string, whereas the `[string]` type is *immutable*.</sup>

- Re 3:

It *is* possible to combine the two approaches - P/Invoke signatures `[DllImport(...` with `-MemberType` on the one hand, and a custom type definition (`class BasicTest ...`) with `-TypeDefinition` on the other (for background information on both approaches, see the bottom of this post).

<sup>Side note re `script` scope: `script` is the default scope inside scripts, so at the top level of a script, all variables you create are implicitly script-scoped; thus, `$script:Shell32 = ...` is effectively the same as `$Shell32 = ...` in the top-level scope of a script. You can even reference that script-level variable from inside a function as just `$Shell32` (though you may wish to use `$script:Shell32` for clarity). The only time you *need* the `$script:` scope qualifiers is if you've created a *local* `$Shell32` variable (e.g., implicitly, simply by *assigning* to `$Shell32`) that *shadows* the script-level one.</sup>

- The code below is a refactoring that creates a single helper class with `Add-Type -TypeDefinition` into which the P/Invoke signatures are integrated (no need for a separate `Add-Type -MemberDefinition` call).

  - The helper type created has only *one* *static* method, `GetVerbName()`. Note that I've removed the `public` access modifier from the P/Invoke signatures to make them private, because they're now only needed *class-internally*.
  - The helper method loads and frees the `"shell32.dll` DLL on every call, but I don't expect that to be a problem performance wise.
  - You could expand this approach to move *all* your non-PowerShell code into this helper class (calling the `Shell.Application` COM object). If you did that, and implemented, say, a `PinToTaskBar` static method, you could simply reference `[PxTools.TaskBarStartMenuHelper]::PinToTaskBar()` from anywhere in your script, and needn't even worry about script-level variables.
- I've replaced the `$verbs` hashtable with a cleaner `Enum` definition, but note that this only works in PSv5+.

```
Enum TaskBarStartMenuVerbs {  
  PinToStartMenu = 5384
  UnpinFromStartMenu = 5385 
  PinToTaskbar = 5386
  UnpinFromTaskbar = 5387
}

Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace PxTools {    
  public class TaskBarStartMenuHelper {
    
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
    static extern int LoadString(IntPtr h, uint id, System.Text.StringBuilder sb, int maxBuffer); 
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")] 
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string s);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")] 
    static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr h);
    
    public static string GetVerbName(uint verbId) {
      IntPtr h = LoadLibrary("shell32.dll");
      const int maxLen = 255;
      var sb = new StringBuilder(maxLen);
      LoadString(h, verbId, sb, maxLen);
      FreeLibrary(h);
      return sb.ToString();
    }         
  }    
}
'@ 

# This returns 'Pin to tas&kbar' on a US English system.
[PxTools.TaskBarStartMenuHelper]::GetVerbName([TaskBarStartMenuVerbs]::PinToTaskbar)
```

<sup>Also note that it's fine to call `Add-Type` repeatedly in a session, as long as the type definition hasn't changed. Subsequent invocations are effectively a fast and silent no-op.

In other words: no need to explicitly check for a type's existence and define it *conditionally*. If a *different* type of the same name is already loaded, the `Add-Type` will fail, which, however is desirable, because you want to make sure that you're using the type you want.</sup>

---

#### Background Information re `-MemberDefinition`

Reference: [`Get-Help Add-Type`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849914(v=wps.650).aspx).

- The first approach - `AddType -MemberDefinition ... -Name ... -NameSpace` is typically used to pass a **string containing public [P/Invoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) signatures** that **enable access to native code such as Windows API functions** via a custom **helper class** that exposes them as **static methods**.

  - When executing the first command, type `[PxTools.Util]` is created with static methods `[PxTools.Util]::LoadString()` and `[PxTools.Util]::LoadLibrary()` that call the underlying Windows API functions.
  - While `-MemberDefinition` is *typically* used with P/Invoke signatures, it is not limited to that, because `-MemberDefinition` is just *syntactic sugar for wrapping the specified string in a public class* (see below for details). Thus, you can pass anything that is valid *inside a `class` body*, such as property and method definitions, as a way of defining your custom class more succinctly, without having to include explicit `namespace` and `class` blocks.
    Note, however, that it is *invariably a `class` that is created*, so you cannot use this approach to define a `struct`, for instance; also, you cannot use `using` statements directly; instead, pass the namespaces via the `-UsingNamespace` parameter.
  - Not specifying a `-NameSpace` value places the type in namespace `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddType.AutoGeneratedTypes`, meaning that you'll have to refer to it as `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddType.AutoGeneratedTypes.<yourTypeName>]` (note how that differs from a `-TypeDefinition` command without a `namespace <name> { ... }` enclosure - see below).
- The second approach - `Add-Type -TypeDefinition ...` - is used to **define a custom type (class)** by way of a **string containing C# source code** (by default; VisualBasic and JScript are also supported).
  A custom type can be a `class`, `delegate`, `enum`, `interface`, or `struct` definition, typically enclosed in a namespace declaration.

  - When executing the 2nd command, type `[BasicTest]` is created (without a namespace qualification, because the type definition in the source-code string isn't enclosed in `namespace <name> { ... }`), with static method `Add` and instance method `Multiply`.

In both cases members must be declared as `public` in order to be accessible from PowerShell.

Note that the **`-MemberDefinition` syntax is essentially just syntactic sugar** in that it automatically provides a class wrapper around the P/Invoke signatures to **facilitate access to native DLL calls in cases where you want to call them *directly*** from PowerShell rather than use them internally in a custom type defined with `Add-Type -TypeDefinition`.

**Example**:

The following `-MemberDefinition` call:

```
Add-Type -Namespace PxTools -Name Utility -MemberDefinition @'
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int LoadString(IntPtr h, uint id, System.Text.StringBuilder sb, int maxBuffer);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string s);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")] 
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr h);
'@
```

is syntactic sugar for the following `-TypeDefinition` call:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PxTools {
  public class Utility {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int LoadString(IntPtr h, uint id, System.Text.StringBuilder sb, int maxBuffer);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string s);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")] 
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr h);
  }  
}
'@
```

In other words: `Add-Type -MemberDefinition`:

- **automatically wraps the *public static* methods defined in the source code in a *public class* with the specified name (`-Name`) in the specified namespace (`-NameSpace`)**, so that these methods can be called as static methods on that class, as **`[<NameSpace>.<Name>]::<Method>(...)`**

  - While this is typically used to expose  P/Invoke signatures - calls to unmanaged functions, notably Windows API functions - it is not limited to that, and you can also use the technique to generally define general-purpose helper classes with (public) static utility methods containing regular (managed) C# code. Note that you cannot use `using` statements directly; instead, pass the namespaces via the `-UsingNamespace` parameter.
- **implicitly prepends the necessary `using` statements** needed to support compilation of the P/Invoke signatures.

Comment: Thanks mklement0. The bit about here-strings is exactly what I was looking at and wondering if it made sense. I guess my next question is, could the first approach be refactored to use the second approach, and what would the differences be? Or is that basically a C# coding question, not a PowerShell implementation question?

Comment: Looking forward to it! Regarding your comments above. 1: I find the colon EASIER to read, as it ties the value and parameter together, rather than using the same white space as between pairs. If I was working on a team I would use spaces, and I should probably use spaces here too, since that's most common. 2: I THINK I understand why StringBuilder is required internally. I am passing $verb to LoadString  empty (by Ref I assume) and expecting it to come back filled, so I can't use a regular, immutable String. 3: The final code is a function in a module, so script scope makes sense.

Comment: But, with regards to Script scope, that only applies when making $shell32 a singleton, and perhaps there just isn't any real reason to do this when the function in question is rarely called more than 5-10 times in a session. I'll probably make it local and profile the performance a bit. Unless there is a way to actually pull that into the Type as well.

Comment: @Gordon: OK, I think I have a working solution now. I've also incorporated the feedback from your later comments.

Comment: Awesome mklement0! Thanks for the great detail. I have now implemented both approaches myself, which has me on the way to actually understanding it. ;) I suspect I will use the less sweet approach, as too much syntactic sugar is like using aliases for me, it's harder to understand when I come back to it months later. Especially true since I am just dipping my toe into C# in any form, so i might as well learn how I would have to do it in a pure C# app. At least for now. I can refactor later if it makes sense.

Comment: One tangential question, which I asked over at SuperUser, relates to what is available in shell32.dll. I'll just link to that question, in the hopes that you have some insights there too.
http://superuser.com/questions/1140247/shell32-dll-string-table-changes

Comment: @Gordon: Glad to hear it helped; my code actually corrects the values of the first 2 verb constants, `PinToStartMenu = 5384` and
  `UnpinFromStartMenu = 5385` - I simply found them by assuming they'd be adjacent to their taskbar equivalents.

Comment: mklement0, have you tested that as well? I used Resource Hacker to look in the DLL, and I see 5386, "Pin to tas&kbar" as well as the description string 5388, "Pins this application to the task bar." But I don't see an action string to go with 5384, "Adds this item to the Start Menu". And, if I just assume English and don't do the string search, "Adds this item to the Start Menu" doesn't work, but "Pin to Start" does. At least in 10.0.10240.0. Once the Anniversary Update is installed, it's broken again, and I don't know yet if the PEB hack is still available or if that hole has been closed too.

Comment: @Gordon: Interesting; I've naively assumed that finding a _string_ that sounds like what you're looking automatically means that it works as an _action_, but it sounds like that's not the case. I know little about Shell32.dll, but is using a localized string really the only way to invoke this functionality?

Comment: My understanding is that it is. But only because that's what the code I found did, and that code used StringBuilder unnecessarily, so I think it's time to build a little test jig that just uses the english &Pin to Start and run it on a French machine and see what happens. Maybe there was never actually a need for this code at all. I'll know tomorrow, when my friend in Paris is back in the office.

Comment: Well, at least in Windows 7 it seems that there is a difference. Using the string derived from 5386, "Pin to Tas&kbar" works, but the one from 5388, "Pins this application to the task bar." does not. The next test is to see if "Pin to Tas&kbar" actually works on different languages, but my guess is that the Verb is actually set dynamically from the language specific MUI file, and the verb in $verb.DoIt() needs to match what is seen in the UI. But, since that info is not in the Win10 MUI, I wonder where the OS looks to get the info to build the UI.Hrmmmm.