# PowerShell web scraping doesn't work in background

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, web-scraping, scripting, background

I wrote a script that works fine:

```
# Use Internet Explorer
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true # Make it visible
# Set Credentials
$username="name.surname@mail.com"
$password="password"
#Navigate to URL
$ie.Navigate("https://service.post.ch/zopa/dlc/app/?service=dlc-web&inMobileApp=false&inIframe=false&lang=fr#!/main")
While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}
# Login 
$usernamefield = $ie.document.getElementByID('isiwebuserid')
$usernamefield.value = "$username"
$passwordfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('isiwebpasswd')
$passwordfield.value = "$password"
$Link = $ie.document.getElementByID('actionLogin')
$Link.click()
Start-Sleep -seconds 5
# Find file to download
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | where-object {$_.innerText -like 'post_adressdaten*'}
$link.click()
Start-Sleep -seconds 3
# Press "Alt + s" on the download dialog  
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%s")
Start-Sleep -seconds 3
# Quit Internet Explorer
$ie.Quit()
```

But if I change `$ie.Visible= $true` to `$ie.Visible= $false` the script doesn't work.

Why?

Because of these two lines:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%s")
```

In these two lines I'm working on the download dialog box of Internet Explorer and if the browser works in background the the script cannot click on it.

How can I send the input in background or in alternative how to keep Internet Explorer always on top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your own answer implies, in order to be able **to send keystrokes** to an application **with [`[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait)**, it must have **a window that is (a) *visible* and (b) has the (input) *focus***.

A simpler and faster alternative to the technique shown in your answer - where you use ad-hoc compilation of C# code that wraps WinAPI functions via P/Invoke declarations, via [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) - is the following:

```
# Create an Internet Explorer instance and make it visible.
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'; $ie.Visible= $true

# Activate it (give it the focus), via its PID (process ID).
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).AppActivate(
  (Get-Process iexplore | Where-Object MainWindowHandle -eq $ie.hWnd).Id
)
```

---

**Taking a step back**:

- GUI scripting (automating a task by *simulating user input* to a GUI) is inherently *unreliable*; for instance, the user may click away from the window that is expected to have the focus.
- While there is no built in solution, it sounds like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) offers *robust* programmatic browser control.

  - The third-party [`Selenium` PowerShell module](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell) is a PowerShell-friendly wrapper for it ([available via the PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Selenium) and therefore with `Install-Module Selenium`), but I don't know if it still works (the project is looking for maintainers as of this writing).

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I have found is this and it's ugly as hell:

```
# Start Internet Explorer on top
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public class Win32SetWindow {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    }
"@

$ie = new-object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application;
$ie.visible = $true;

    [Win32SetWindow]::SetForegroundWindow($ie.HWND) # <--   Internet Explorer window on top

# Set Credentials
$username="name.surname@mail.com"
$password="password"
#Navigate to URL
$ie.Navigate("https://service.post.ch/zopa/dlc/app/?service=dlc-web&inMobileApp=false&inIframe=false&lang=fr#!/main")
While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}
# Login 
$usernamefield = $ie.document.getElementByID('isiwebuserid')
$usernamefield.value = "$username"
$passwordfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('isiwebpasswd')
$passwordfield.value = "$password"
$Link = $ie.document.getElementByID('actionLogin')
$Link.click()
Start-Sleep -seconds 5
# Find file to download
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | where-object {$_.innerText -like 'post_adressdaten*'}
$link.click()
Start-Sleep -seconds 3
# Press "Alt + s" on the download dialog  
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%n{TAB}{ENTER}")     # or use SendWait("%s")
Start-Sleep -seconds 3
# Quit Internet Explorer
$ie.Quit()
```

Comment: Good to see an example of using P/Invoke from PowerShell (even though it turned out not to be needed in this case). Note that `Add-Type` has syntactic sugar for creating P/Invoke wrappers, namely when you use `-MemberDefinition` instead of `-TypeDefinition`; see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40297122/45375) for background information.

Comment: Thank you for your help @mklement0. However I'm not completely satisfied with my code. If the user put it on the background forcefully or if the user click on another window during the process the input focus is lost. 
Do you have any other alternative to login into a web page and download?

Comment: Yes, GUI scripting is always brittle. I have no personal experience with it, but perhaps [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) can help; the third-party [Selenium PowerShell Module](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell) is a PowerShell wrapper for it, but I don't know if it still works (the project is looking for maintainers).